# Create an "IRC shell-account" on private IRC server

Tags: linux, shell, ssl, irc

As *this* question did not receive any informative answers:
[ [Setting up linux shell accounts for public access](https://superuser.com/questions/771601/setting-up-linux-shell-accounts-for-public-access) ] I would like to rephrase the original question for my own purposes:

I would **like** to create, what is colloquially known on IRC as, "a shell account" on my own Linux server for my own personal use (there is no security issue at stake, I can shoot myself if I do something stupid) - I would like this so that I can install this server in a remote location and then connect to the IRC user (myself) which I would like logged into my own private IRC server 24 hours a day.  My location will be regularly changing so I cannot remain logged in from my local site at all times. I would like to connect over an SSL enabled connection.

I admit that I do not know if this is possible with *standard Linux*, so if this is something which requires third party software please point me in a suitable direction as so far google has been remarkably vague ..

**If i have completely misunderstood** the *term* or *use* of "IRC shell accounts" any further advice is appreciated.

Many thanks

**Edit:** I cannot improve the question .. I did not understand that "IRC Shell Accounts" were nothing more than "standard shell accounts".

I will say that I got two replies which understood my question and provided both long and short answers. Perhaps if this question is left as is and **without** the demotion it will provide help to others.

Please go ahead with `close`

Answer (score 1):

"Shell accounts" are really *nothing more* than a regular user account on a regular Linux / BSD system, usually accessed over the SSH protocol.

(Most public providers usually pre-install various common software, set some resource limits, run an email server for users; [some old ones](http://sdf.org/?dialup) even act as ISPs; they often have a *community* built around their system... but that's irrelevant here.)

#### Howto

So step 0 is to **actually *have* a server** – ideally, running Linux or some BSD variant.

- Some use their own hardware hosted somewhere with a 24/7 network connection, e.g. at a colocation facility, or at their workplace, or even at home (assuming the ISP allows that). A static-ish, publicly accessible IP address is needed.
- Others simply rent a dedicated server from companies like OVH, or a VPS from Linode or DigitalOcean or many other providers.

Step 1 is to **enable remote access – install the SSH service** (OpenSSH). Often it already comes as part of the basic OS installation, and you only need to start/enable the `sshd` daemon.

Step 2 is to **create a user account** for yourself, in case you haven't done this yet. (The tools are `adduser` on Debian, `useradd` on Arch, `pw user add` on FreeBSD, and so on.)

Well, that's basically it. You have a "shell account", into which you can ssh remotely, run tools like `tmux` or `screen` (for the "attaching/detaching" part), and IRC clients like `irssi` or `weechat`.

#### Security

Though you **really should** do a few more things.

In particular, remember that the entire IPv4 address space is frequently scanned by botnets looking for insecure systems & easily guessable passwords, and most likely they'll start beating on your door within *minutes* of enabling SSH.

So an important part of OpenSSH configuration is to a) have a strong password, or b) learn how to use **[SSH public-key auth](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+public-key+authentication)** and disable password logins entirely. (Which is a separate topic.)

Similarly, if your chosen OS supports automatic updates (e.g. Ubuntu's unattended-upgrades), you *should* use them. Public providers go even further, by setting up grsec or SELinux or systrace or AppArmor, but for a private personal server it's probably overkill – unless the distro already has done the integration for you, as e.g. Fedora does.

(The security issue here is not just about *you*; it's also about your system getting abused to attack *other* systems.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry I skipped over the part where you mention screen/tmux and so did not respond to you first.

Answer (score 1):

You either want to install a so called "Bouncer" (BNC) which supports SSL connection.

Or you might use a combination of ssh + screen/tmux and an IRC console client (like irssi).

Also there are websites that offer similar functionality: https://www.irccloud.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply: screen/tmux sounds very much like what I am looking for. According to (https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Screen_vs_tmux?) the bit that I am interested in is: "_Both GNU Screen and tmux allow the user to detach and reattach terminal sessions, leaving any shells and their subprocesses managed by the multiplexer while detached._" Following further investigation and achieving my goal I will mark this as the solution (if indeed it is) very soon.

Comment: `screen` works well for my simple requirements.